# How to pass a string in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

So I have a URL within  `Method1` like so

```
public void Method1 (String x) {
    String Url = "http://MYURL.com/?country=" + x + "&api_key=APIKEY";
    new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();
}
```

I need to pass the Url into my AsyncTask which is as follows

```
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)  {

        try {
            // create new instance of the httpConnect class
            httpConnect jParser = new httpConnect();

            // get json string from service url
            String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(ServiceUrl);

            // save returned json to your test string
            jsonTest = json.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {
        textLastLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastlocation);
        textLastLocation.setText(jsonTest);
    }
}
```

I need it so the `ServiceUrl` = the Url from the method. I can't figure out how to do this even from looking at other peoples questions and answers

Comment: Pass the url in execute()

Comment: so it would be new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute(Url);? How do I then use the string in the AsyncTask?

Comment: Read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
First class in the base class is for the type of arguments in `doInBackground()`. Third class is what `doInBackground()` returns and `onPostExecute()` recieves. Second is the progress type, which is recieved by `onProgressUpdate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter on `AsyncTask<First, Second, Third>` will define the parameter to be passed on `execute()`, so you define it as `String` and pass the url. Then:

```
public void Method1 (String x) {
   String Url = "http://MYURL.com/?country=" + x + "&api_key=APIKEY";
   new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute(url);
}
```

On your AsyncTask, you can get it on the `arg0 (array)`, i(ndex based on the order on how you passed it on `execute()`)

```
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {}

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)  {
    String url = arg0[0]; // this is your passed url
    try {
        // create new instance of the httpConnect class
        httpConnect jParser = new httpConnect();

        // get json string from service url
        String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(ServiceUrl);

        // save returned json to your test string
        jsonTest = json.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {
    textLastLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lastlocation);
    textLastLocation.setText(jsonTest);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer. However where you had "String url = arg0[0];" should have been "String ServiceUrl = arg0[0];"

Comment: Your welcome, I've just explain it generically not specifying for url only, it means you can also pass more data on execute(url, anotherUrl, anotherData).